# Sparksql read json with inner array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read json into dataset (spark 2.3.2). Unfortunately it doesn't works well  .

Here is the data ,it's  a json file with a inner array

```
{ "Name": "helloworld", 
  "info": { "privateInfo": [ {"salary":1200}, {"sex":"M"}],
            "house": "sky road" 
          }, 
  "otherinfo":2
}   
{ "Name": "helloworld2",
  "info": { "privateInfo": [ {"sex":"M"}],
            "house": "sky road" 
          }, 
  "otherinfo":3
}
```

I use sparksession to select the columns, but it has some problems: the result is not the data itself，but in an array.

```
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT name , info.privateInfo.salary ,info.privateInfo.sex   FROM people1 ")
    sqlDF.show()
```

But columns `salary` & `sex` are in an array:

```
+-----------+-------+-----+
|       name| salary|  sex|
+-----------+-------+-----+
| helloworld|[1200,]|[, M]|
|helloworld2|     []|  [M]|
+-----------+-------+-----+
```

How could I get the data with the datatype itself?

Such as

```
+-----------+-------+-----+
|       name| salary|  sex|
+-----------+-------+-----+
| helloworld|  1200 |  M  |
|helloworld2|none/null| M |
+-----------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer

```
spark.sql("SELECT name , " +
      "element_at(filter(info.privateInfo.salary, salary -> salary is not null), 1) AS salary ," +
      "element_at(filter(info.privateInfo.sex, sex -> sex is not null), 1) AS sex" +
      "   FROM people1 ")

+-----------+------+---+
|       name|salary|sex|
+-----------+------+---+
| helloworld|  1200|  M|
|helloworld2|  null|  M|
+-----------+------+---+
```

Long answer
The main concern is the array nullability

```
root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- house: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- privateInfo: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- salary: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- sex: string (nullable = true)
 |-- otherinfo: long (nullable = true)
```

So we need a way to filter out null values, luckily spark `2.4` has built-in [Higher-Order Functions](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html)

The first attempt was to use `array_remove`, but unfortunately `null` can never be equal to `null`.
It is still possible with more verbose syntax

```
df.selectExpr("filter(info.privateInfo.salary, salary -> salary is not null)")

+------+
|salary|
+------+
|[1200]|
|    []|
+------+
```

Now we need some way to explode the array, luckily us spark has `explode` function!

```
df.selectExpr(
 "explode(filter(info.privateInfo.salary, salary -> salary is not null)) AS salary",
 "explode(filter(info.privateInfo.sex, sex -> sex is not null)) AS sex")
```

Boom

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Only one generator allowed per select clause but found 2
```

As we know there should be exactly one value in the array, we can use `element_at`

```
 df.selectExpr(
      "element_at(filter(info.privateInfo.salary, salary -> salary is not null), 1) AS salary",
      "element_at(filter(info.privateInfo.sex, sex -> sex is not null), 1) AS sex")
```

p.s. haven't noticed it was asked 10 months ago